# How do I get value from another filter in a django filter set

Tags: python, django

I have a custom django filter and I want to get the value of "distance" inside the filter_location function, any ideas how I achieve this?

Reason for wanting to do so, I am doing an external API call to get data and need both the values at the same time.

```
class ListingFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    def filter_location(self, queryset, value):
        # Want to get the distance filter value here
        if value:
            #Location value


    def filter_distance(self, queryset, value):
        pass

    distance = django_filters.CharFilter(label='Distance', method=filter_distance)
    location = django_filters.CharFilter(label='Location', method=filter_location)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['distance', 'service', 'tags', 'location']


class CompanyListView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    filter_class = ListingFilter
```

Answer (score 8):

everything is in `self.data` as an ordered dict:

```
class ListingFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def filter_location(self, queryset, value):
        print(self.data['distance'])
        return queryset
```